# string breaking/stripping using a mysql query

Tags: mysql, vb.net, string

i have a column that i want to select from a table called style_number

each entry is listed as "something-stylenumber"

is there a way to strip everything from the - and to the left from the string when it is returned from mysql?

```
SELECT style_number FROM table1
```

I do not want to have to use vb.net to edit the returned string for each line that is pulled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(style_number, INSTR(style_number, '-') +1 ) FROM table1
```